# Windows Store App Corner Radius

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am trying to develop a ListView with rounded corners.
The rounded corners property is working, however I am having some issue when the top or bottom item is selected. At that point, the rounded corners are replaced.

Selecting some node inbetween top and bottom items is OK:

[image]

However this is what happens with top and bottom items:

[image]

*I know about the trick in .Net WPF apps where you would normally use Clipping with round corners. But, WinRT doesnt seem to support rounded corners in clipping.

Comment: Try taking a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle I don't know if it will do what you want but its worth a try.

Comment: How are you rounding your corners now? If your background is solid color - the easiest approach would be to overlay solid filled roundings on top of your corners. Otherwise you might want to update `ItemContainerStyle` as mydogisbox suggested and perhaps make the highlight/selection bar rounded too.

Comment: Indeed, I am modifying the ItemContainerStyle of the list view control. In this case the container has a border control. I am setting the CornerRadius property. 
Your suggestion seems feasible(more like a trick you would perform in web design though). I was looking for some other solution(maybe more elegant or something else as I am kind of new to XAML)

Comment: Since nenrect clip geometries are not supported - the only options are hacky or require cutting corners. :)

Comment: @d0kt0r1 You said you're modifying the CornerRadius of the border, but are you also doing it for the Selection Border, including the EarMark?

Comment: @Nate, modifying the selection border would trigger rounded borders for all items I guess. I do not want such thing

Comment: @d0kt0r1 If the items knew their position in the list, you could bind the selection border through a converter to that.

Comment: Hi, it's considered polite to mark the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, so, look...

Let me answer the question with this example:

```
<Border Width="100" Height="100" Margin="5"
    Background="DimGray" CornerRadius="15">
</Border>

<Border Width="100" Height="100" Margin="5"
    Background="DimGray" CornerRadius="15">
    <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Purple" />
</Border>

<Border Width="100" Height="100" Margin="5" Padding="5"
    Background="DimGray" CornerRadius="15">
    <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Purple" />
</Border>

<Border Width="100" Height="100" Margin="5" Padding="5"
    Background="Purple" CornerRadius="15">
    <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Purple" />
</Border>
```

Looks like this:

[image]

And, why? Because clipping in Windows 8 currently only supports a rectangle. Not a polygon, not a rounded corner, not anything. That 4th item in the sample is really your only approach at this time. At least you have an option!

Best of luck!